# Android widget click not working

Tags: android, android-widget

I've been trying to add configuration screen for my widget and I'm having problems getting it to work.  The configuration screen comes up fine when I first add the widget to my home screen, but it's supposed to also come up when the user clicks on the widget.  That's the part that is not working.

Here's the onUpdate code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetConfiguration.class);            
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);  
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);            
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.temperatureWidget, pendingIntent);
```

Here's the xml for the widget layout (widget.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/frame"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:id="@+id/temperatureWidget">
<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="15px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/img_thermometer"/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_marginTop="35px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="  Temp: "/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="35px"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/txtTemperature"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the widget, nothing happens.  Any ideas?

Comment: RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

I don't see R.layout.widget defined in the XML you posted. Are you sure that you are not referring to two different XMLs?

Comment: The Xml I posted is a layout file called widget.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a line as given in appwidget docs

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  I can't believe I missed that after staring at the example docs for hours.

Comment: If it is the answer, then check it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it is something in your xml layout for the widget.  Are you sure that `R.id.temperatureWidget` is clickable?  Is that a button or is that what your actually layout named?

Comment: Yes, it's clickable.  It is the LinearLayout of the widget.  I'll add the lay code as well.